# can't get reset password to work

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have a project that sends a link to reset a password. The problem is that the link shows localhost...... instead of localhost:8000 .
Below is the message on the email.

If you’re having trouble clicking the "Reset Password" button, copy and paste the URL below into your web browser: http://localhost/password/reset/62c2ba9cf1d48f0291451e8be42a8b792cb1fd38e682e7bdcd5919b1d56365e4

If I manually type localhost:8000 it works. Where in the settings, for laravel 5.4, can I change this? Plus, I can't seem to find my Illuminate folder. Not sure if the solution is in there.

Comment: It would be a better idea to run your web server on the default HTTP port 80. Then this would not be an issue,

Comment: When/If you come to move this site to a LIVE web server, it will be on port 80

Comment: This is just a test site. As I am learning about laravel.  So is there a way to change the port?

Comment: Do you mean you are using PHP's builtin web server?

Comment: `http://localhost:8000/ ...` ? Seems a little odd, defaults are 80 and 8080 aren't they?

Comment: @CD001 80 is the default.

Comment: That is not what I have been learning.

Comment: What is not what you have been learning?

Comment: Maybe for laravel it is different.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I know that `80` is the default default, but isn't `8080` used as a secondary default commonly ... if that makes sense?

Comment: No, Laravel runs on a web server EG Apache and Apache shoudl run on port 80

Comment: @CD001 Yea sorry get what you are on about now

Comment: Well I have changed nothing.

Comment: What web server are you running? Is it on Windows or a *nix

Comment: I am using it on a Mac.

Comment: Then amend your httpd.conf file to use port 80

Answer (score 0):

You could use $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'], this will give you your port, then you can use it in your script when generating the url.
[PHP $_SERVER - Manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: That does not work. Here is code for my button `<a href="{{  $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] }}" class="button button-{{ $color or 'blue' }}" target="_blank">{{ $slot }}</a>`

Comment: I myself use the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], when i use this on localhost:8180, it gives me localhost:8180, ready for use

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. You have to stop your server and then change  `APP_URL=http://localhost:8000` in the .env file.